# The method listFiles(Path, boolean) is undefined for the type FileSystem

Tags: java, hadoop, filesystems, fs

I am getting The method listFiles(Path, boolean) is undefined for the type FileSystem. Has anyone came across this issue ?

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> itr =  fs.listFiles(srcPath,true);
```

Comment: Make sure you have the right import.

Comment: Looks like there isn't a listFiles in FileSystem.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably importing the java Filesystem, not the Apache one. Check your imports.

Comment: Here are my Import.
`import java.io.IOException;`
`import java.util.ArrayList;`
`import java.util.List;`
`import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;'
'import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;'
'import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;'
'import org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus;'
'import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;'
'import org.apache.hadoop.fs.RemoteIterator;'

Comment: Hm, those look right. I wonder if something is wrong with your libraries. Which IDE are you using? When you type  "fs.", which methods does autocomplete list?

Comment: There was probably a Dependancy conflict. i recreated the Project and it works...Thanks...